# Linearly dependence of a vector set in a real vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Is a vector set that belongs to a real vector space defined linearly dependent, iff the span of the set is equal to the zero vector?

Comment: Read the first paragraph of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence

Comment: The  collections for which the span is $\vec 0$ can only contain $\vec 0$.   I mean, the collections are of the form $\{\vec 0\}$, $\{\vec 0, \vec 0\}$ and so on.

Comment: That looks like a very verbose definition to indicate exactly two subsets.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}
\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{ #1 \}}
$
Note that if $S$ contains any nonzero vector, then $\span(S) \supsetneq \set{\vec 0}$. Namely, because if $s \ne \vec 0$ is in $S$, then $\set{\vec 0} \ne \set s \subseteq \span(S)$.

So, we have to ask, what of the cases $S = \set{\vec 0}$ and $S = \varnothing$? (At least in my experience, we often define $\span(\varnothing) = \set{\vec 0}$, so it should be considered too.)

You can show that any singleton set is linearly independent. You can also show that $\varnothing$ is linearly independent, through vacuous reasoning and the fact that $\varnothing$ cannot be linearly dependent.

I'll leave the details of proving these facts, and seeing how they apply to your situation, to you.